# Azure Text to Speech API: only mono output formats (no stereo formats) available?

Tags: c#, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I've been developing a Text-to-Speech app with Azure SDK and according to reference page below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechsynthesisoutputformat?view=azure-dotnet

there seems to be only mono output formats available and it is not possible to create audio files in stereo format, correct? If there's anyone familiar with this, please help me out with your answer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What would be the benefit of a stereo format? It would be exactly the same data in both left and right channels, thus (unless wav files reuse information) a doubling of the file size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @gunr2171. OK, I see there should be no point to have a stereo format option in TTS then. I have a little bit tricky situation where sometimes TTS audio files I create are first converted to a stereo format and placed into a movie file with its stereo audio data while this original audio data needs to be kept alive in the movie file. So I was asked whether it was possible to create TTS audio files in a stereo format in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only mono formats are supported as for now (Feb, 2022) by Azure TTS. I suggest you to use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to convert the audio file from mono to stereo.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thank you for your answer. If Azure provided a stereo option, I thought it would be way better to use it because that way, we might be able to avoid the risk of compromising the audio quality using a third party tool that we are using but you have convinced me with your answer that there is no stereo option in Azure TTS. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per Azure cognitive services base documentation there are nearly 20 different types of audio output types, we can get using Azure SDK using REST API.

All those outputs are mono type only. Not stereo type.

By default, azure SDK using REST API is providing mono format of audio. That is single channel output.

Comment: sorry for my late reply and thank you for your answer.